# How Stream.Read writes/accesses to buffer parameter without passing ref keyword?

Tags: c#

Just wondering how It could be done and I'm at a point where I am implementing the `stream.Read` method. Am I missing something or there is just a `ref` keyword missing or what?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] ex = new byte[1] { 0 };
    MessageBox.Show(ex[0].ToString());
    ok(ex);
    MessageBox.Show(ex[0].ToString());
}

private int ok(byte[] asd)
{
    asd = new byte[1] { 255 };
    return 1;
}

//first result: 0
//second result: 0
```

Comment: instead of `asd = new byte[1] { 255 };` do `asd[0] = 255;`

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, it's not. Please read my answer. "Pass by  reference" and "pass reference by value" are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @Jon I stand corrected, thanks. Removed incorrect comments to avoid misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a matter of understanding two important concepts:

- [The difference between reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html)
- [How arguments are passed in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html)

Your `ok` method changes the value of the *parameter* - that *won't* be visible to the caller, because it's a value parameter (the argument is passed by value). However, if you were to write:

```
asd[0] = 255;
```

instead of the first line, then that change *would* be visible. That's not changing the parameter itself; it's changing the value of an element within the object that the parameter refers to.

Basically, the value of an expression in .NET is never an object - it's always either a value type value or a *reference* - a way of explaining how to *get* to an object.

Suppose I hand you a piece of paper with my home address on. If you rub out that address and write on a different address, that doesn't change where I live, does it? That's what you're doing when you change the parameter value. However, if you go to the address on the piece of paper and paint the front door red, then I'll see a red front door when I come home. You haven't changed the value on the piece of paper - you've made a change within the object that the value on the piece of paper refers to. That's what `Stream.Read` does.

Answer (score 1):

Array's (which is the first parameter of `stream.Read`) are passed by reference to object in heap (so you have access to object itself but don't have access to variable that hold's this reference in calling code) and you don't need `ref` keyword to change array elements, but do when you ned to instantiate a new array and set it to reference.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about you're right. (check my edit code and run it)

Comment: stream.Read doesn't create a new array, it writes to one you passed it.

Comment: No, arrays aren't passed by reference - the reference is passed by value.

Comment: How could I miss this... thanks but.. I think stream.Read reads blocks.. It seems without equalizing passed array with a new array, there is just only way equalizing one by one.. It takes time.. But I'm quite sure It doesn't takes that much time

Comment: @haxxoromer: you really need to take a deeper look at reference types and value types. In your code, "ex" is a reference to an array, which is copied into a local variable "asd" when you call ok() so they refer to the same array object when ok() begins to run. Then you reassign "asd", but that will do nothing to your original array and your "ex" reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet Array is class, so it's passed by reference, or am i wrong?

Comment: @PavelKrymets: You're wrong. Please read the links in my answer. There's a big difference between "pass reference by value" and "pass by reference".

Comment: @Alan how could I point to array with the referance that I've passed with value (parameter asd)

Comment: @PavelKrymets: "Passed by reference value" isn't really a well-understood piece of terminology though... I certainly wouldn't expect it to help anyone who doesn't already understand what's going on.

Comment: @haxxoromer: Imagine that the references "ex" and "asd" are pieces of paper that have the 'address' of the actual array written on them. When you call the method, the "ex" paper is taken, its contents are copied onto another piece of paper, then this second one is placed into "asd". Now you have two pieces of paper with the same text, but the actual object (the array) they 'refer to' is the same.

Comment: @haxxoromer: Now once you erase the "asd" paper and write something else on it, this will do nothing to either the "ex" paper or the array object itself.

Comment: @PavelKrymets: You're still using "passed by reference value" which is a non-standard term. I agree with the rest of the answer, but on its own I don't think it actually helps much.